# How to include a value from .some in an output?

Tags: javascript, loops, if-statement, reduce

I'm checking whether words aren't contracted in a `sentences` array:

```js
const sentences = ['i do not', 'aren\'t you']

const result = sentences.reduce((result, sentence, index, array) => {
  const noncontractions = ['do not', 'are not']
  const isNoncontraction = noncontractions.some(noncontraction => sentence.includes(noncontraction))

  if (isNoncontraction) {
    result.push(sentence)
  }

  return result
}, [])

console.log(result) // list of sentences that aren't contracted.
```

Right now, the output is `['i do not']`. But I also want to include the `noncontraction` related to the item.

So the output would look like: `[{ sentence: 'i do not', noncontraction: 'do not'}]`

I'm not sure how to achieve this, since `noncontraction` is in the `.some` "loop."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `find()` rather than `some()`. Then you can combine what was found with the sentence.

```js
const sentences = ['i do not', 'aren\'t you']

const result = sentences.reduce((result, sentence) => {
  const noncontractions = ['do not', 'are not']
  const noncontraction = noncontractions.find(noncontraction => sentence.includes(noncontraction))

  if (noncontraction) {
    result.push({sentence, noncontraction})
  }

  return result
}, [])

console.log(result) // list of sentences that aren't contracted.
```